# Angular 2 Listening for Push Events

Tags: angular, push-notification, service-worker

I'm attempting to listen for push notifications sent by a server in an Angular 2 web app. I've initialized a [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers), service worker script (`sw.js`) and registered for push notifications as follows

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/app/sw.js', { scope: '/app/' }).then(function(reg) {
    // registration worked
    console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
    // register for push notifications
    reg.pushManager.subscribe({
       userVisibleOnly: true;
    }).then(
        function(subscription) {
           console.log('subscription endpoint is ' + subscription.endpoint);
        }, 
        function(err) {
           console.log(err);
        })
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // registration failed
    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
}
```

and in `sw.js` I listen for push events, i.e.,

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('Push message received!', event);
});
```

This all works: the app initializes a `ServiceWorker` and I can receive push notifications in the ServiceWoker thread. However, I want the components of my Angular 2 app to listen for push events, not just the `sw.js` script.

How can I make components of the app listen for push notifications received in the service worker? Or, how can I access the [ServiceWorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/onpush) from within my app?

Comment: Have you tried using a service?

Comment: hey man any update?